# while decode the csv file gives wrong data

Tags: python, decode, encode, odoo-11

I want to decode a `csv` file but it gives the wrong data..

example:  in `csv` file i have `BP1-R241`  after decode the file it gives `BP1+AC0-R241`

if the columns contain `(-,/,\,*,....etc)` it gives `+AC0` is added

How can I rectify this ?

My code:

```
import base64


data = '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'



data = base64.b64decode(data).decode('utf-8')
```

output:-

```
code,quantity,location
123456643,1,BP1+AC0-R241

12345,2,BP1+AC0-R241

123456,3,BP1+AC0-R241

q23234354656,4,BP1+AC0-R241

dsfdsf,5,BP1+AC0-R241

233456,6,BP1+AC0-R241

ddfsdf,7,BP1+AC0-R241

354678,8,BP1+AC0-R241

1234567,9,BP1+AC0-R241

234567,10,BP1+AC0-R241

iu65432,11,BP1+AC0-R241

jhgfd,12,BP1+AC0-R241

xcvfgbhn,13,BP1+AC0-R241

cfcghjk,14,BP1+AC0-R241

sdfghj,15,BP1+AC0-R241

asdfghj,16,BP1+AC0-R241

sadfghjk,17,BP1+AC0-R241

sdsdsdsd,18,BP1+AC0-R241

11223344,19,BP1+AC0-R241

112233442,20,BP1+AC0-R241

TEST123,21,BP1+AC0-R241
```

Answer (score 4):

The data you've pasted in simply *contains* `BP1+AC0-R241`, there's no way around it.

The problem is not in decoding, it's in wherever you get that data from.

Googling "+AC0" leads me to [this thread](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=20619), and namely this:

> The data in your file is encoded as UTF-7 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-7), instead of the more usual ascii/latin-1 or UTF-8. Each of the +ACI- sequences encodes one double quote character.

Are you *sure* you've exported the file as UTF-8, not UTF-7?

Comment: Indeed, you beat me to it. I've seen this one before, too :) Use utf-7 but I'd suggest you also get rid of these before it comes back to bite you in unexpected ways in the future